# Programatically How do I reset colors in PDF

Tags: pdf-generation

I am creating a PDF file and I would like to generate several rectangles on the page
However once I fill  a rectangle in color I cannot reset the fill color (non-stroking color) to 
clear, white, transparent or whatever is needed so that no color is in the rectangle

I use this to set the stroke and non-stroke to red

```
1.0  0.0  0.0 rg
1.0  0.0  0.0 RG
```

I set the line width

```
1 w
```

I draw a rectangle and it appears as a red rectangle (outlined and filled in red)

```
0046.8 0633.6 0237.6 0100.8 re
B
```

Now I set the stroke to black

```
0.0  0.0  0.0 RG
```

I attempt to create another rectangle (I only want black outline)

```
0072.0 0576.0 0288.0 0144.0 re
B
```

But the second rectangle appears with a black outline but is filled in red?
How do I get red of the red fill?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is your use of `B`.  If you interchange the two drawing operations you'll see that (what was) the second rectangle is now filled with *black*, because black is the default color.  You should use `S` for the second rectangle, so that that path is stroked but not filled.

By the way, you're missing some really easy ways to reduce the size of your generated PDF:

- Use `g`/`G` instead of `rg`/`RG` when all three numbers are the same.
- `1 w` is unnecessary (unless returning to that setting from a different one), 1 is the default value for stroke width.
- Don't print trailing `.0` or leading zeroes on your numbers.

Putting all which together, here's what your generated page stream should look like:

```
1 0 0 rg 1 0 0 RG
46.8 633.6 237.6 100.8 re B
0 G
72 576 288 144 re S
```